# Laravel 5: form data won't submit to the database - no error shown

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to assign users as moderators to forum categories (subreddits) in a pivot table called `moderators`

Here are the tables

> moderators: id, user_id, subreddit_id, created_at, updated_at
>
> users: id: name: email...
>
> subreddits: id, user_id, name...

I have created the view, controller and model but data won't submit to the database and I get no error.

Note: I need to visit this route `subreddit/{id}/moderators/create` in order to get to the view and start submitting.

**EDIT:** I just emptied the `store()` function and replaced it with `return 'done';` but that doesn't seem to take effect. Upon clicking the submit button, the page just reloads and nothing happens. So maybe the problem is in the view?

Routes.php

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
Route::resource('subreddit.moderators', 'ModeratorsController');
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
$router->model('articles', 'App\Article');
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');
$router->model('moderators', 'App\Moderator');
```

`Moderator` Model

```
protected $table = 'moderators';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'subreddit_id'];

    public function subreddit() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

`ModeratorsController` - here I am trying to submit the user_id and subreddit_it manually just to test that it is working.

```
public function create(Moderator $moderator, Subreddit $subreddit, User $user)
    {
        $subreddit = Subreddit::with('user')->findOrFail($subreddit->id);

        return view('user/moderators')->with(compact('subreddit'));
    }

public function store(Requests\ModeratorRequest $request, Subreddit $subreddit)
    {
        $moderator = new Moderator;
        $moderator->user_id = 2;
        $moderator->subreddit_id = 17;
        $moderator->save();
    }
```

And this is the form inside the view, I am using Typeahead.js that's why there's div with `id="remote"`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'subreddit/' . $subreddit->id . '/moderators', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

    <p>
        <div id="remote">
            <input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Username" name="user_name">
            <input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="" name="user_id">
        </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::submit('Submit Post', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </p>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

ModeratorRequest

```
public function authorize()
{
   return true;
}

public function rules()
{
   return [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'subreddit_id' => 'required'
   ];
}
```

Comment: Hello again. ;) please post the `ModeratorRequest`. I think the validation error returned is not being displayed by your view so the request will return with no errors.

Comment: Hello again :) I have updated my original post and added ModeratorRequest.

Comment: Added `Request $request` instead of `ModeratorRequest` and it worked. What's wrong with my ModeratorRequest?

Comment: Change the `ModeratorRequest $request` to `Request $request` and see if it works.

Comment: Remove subreddit_id from your validation rules and check again with ModeratorRequest. It should work ;)

Comment: I just posted above :) It works when I do that, but `Request.php` is empty, I need to validate these 2 inputs and make sure they're required.

Comment: No, removing `subreddit_id` didn't work. It stopped submitting to the db altogether.

Comment: The subreddit is required by default due to the route pattern you're using, so no need to validate it.

Comment: try `foreach ($messages->all() as $message)` to see if you still have validation errors in your view.

Comment: @Mithredate Thanks man :) It's working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `foreach ($messages->all() as $message)` according to the [documentations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#working-with-error-messages).

The problem is that your `ModeratorRequest` is returning validations error, which you don't display on the view.